# Whom did Caleb Haas call after running from his mom?

Tags: plot-explanation, quantico

In Quantico, We get all our answers in the end but when Alex Parrish freed Caleb Haas from his mom, he goes to check his bag which he threw out of the window and he makes a call to report someone. In the end the real culprit was Liam who tricked everyone to work for him but Caleb was not involved and he even helps getting justice.

But whom did he call to report what is going on?

Comment: I'm guessing it was Shelby (or atleast that's what I thought when I saw it), though might have to watch the episode again to refresh my memory.